# How do you use Gnash?

Tags: linux, apt

So. Looking over the internet to find some kind of substitute to adobe flash, I landed on the raspberry pi forum or something (Forgot the link). I saw somebody talking about Gnash from GNU, and after attempting to download it from the direct link, I got error 404.

so instead, I scrolled down a bit and started doing some anonymous downloads via the terminal. Attempted using both these lines here;

> git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/gnash.git

This first one worked, but when I tried running a flash program, it didn't really do anything except let the website say that I needed to install adobe flash.

I also tried this:

> sudo apt-get install gnash

But, when I tried this, a nice long string of errors popped up, saying my raspberry pi could't fetch a few required archives, and suggested that I try running this line:

> apt-get update

Forget it. Couldn't open up those locked archives, error shown here:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What does this mean, and is there a really working way to get Gnash for the raspberry pi?

Thanks.

You can try to get gnash here, via the direct link, if you want to test it: `https://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/download.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install using apt-get You need to run apt-get update with sudo as indicated by the last line of output you included in your answer, like this: sudo apt-get update (note: you should run this before installing any package to ensure you get the latest avcailable version). Then rerun sudo apt-get install gnash. This is also the preferred means of installing as it gives you a clear path to remove, purge and update the package - something most other methods of installing software do not include. However, if you need a bleeding edge version of a particular software, installing from source maybe your only option.

As for cloning the git repo, you don't mention what you did beyond fetching the code. Normally you need to compile and install the code you just downloaded. Installation instructions are normally included in the projects readme.md file (note: capitalization of this file may differ).